# Weird Object/class behaviour in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an array of Group. When I call increment, to increment the id of the object (in A) all the IDs of all the object in the array are being incremented. Anyone know why please?

```
 Group [] groups = new Group [g];
    groups[0] = group;
    for (int i=1; i<g;i++){
        groups[i] = groups[i-1];
        groups[i].increment();              .......... A

    }


    public void increment() {
         this.groupid = this.groupid++;
    }
```

Comment: `this.groupid++` should not be assigned back to `this.groupid`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  By any chance is `groupid` marked `static`?  That would account for your behavior.  Can you post the rest of your code for `Group` to make it easier to track down the bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i=1; i<g;i++){
    groups[i] = groups[i-1];
    groups[i].increment();
}
```

Every index of your array refers to the same Group object.

Comment: yeah, group 0 has got ID = 1;

Comment: then group 1 should have ID = 2 and so on. But Everything remains equal to the highest ID assigned

Answer (score 1):

Because you're simply copying references to all the elements of the array. All the elements contain the same instance of Group but different references.

You should either create a new Group object each time in the loop or use a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

First the increment method does not actually work. It should probably be:

```
 public void increment() {
     this.groupid++;
 }
```

Otherwise it wouldn't actually change.

The second problem was already mentioned by other answers, that is, you actually have only one Group object and many references to that one object.